# Cronjob works with regular user but not with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, cron, redhat

So I am trying to familiarize myself with Cronjobs. I have consulted some tutorials on Cronjobs and started trying some things out. First thing I did was I created a file that has the following contents:

[image]

This file is located at:

home/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXX_XXXXXXX/Cronjobs/Scripts

And I created a file in that same folder called cronjobOutput

When I use this command, the text from the script is appended to the cronjobOutput file:

```
bash testscript
```

[image: I translated the testscript content in the first picture to English for the sake of this question]
*I translated the testscript content in the first picture to English for the sake of this question*

After that I used the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

And I added the following:

```
*/1 * * * * home/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXX_XXXXXXX/Cronjobs/Scripts/testscript.sh
```

After a minute I started receiving emails from the crondeamon saying:

**No such file or directory**

So I removed the `.sh` extension and started receiving different emails saying:

**Permission denied**

I looked up the problem and tried to use the following command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This opened a different crontab for the root user where I used the exact same contents as the regular crontab and saved it. This time I did not receive any emails, but it also did not append the text and time to the cronjobOutput file. I also deliberately added the `.sh` extension again to test if I would recieve mails but I did not.

The question is, why does my root crontab not work and my regular one does?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I can't show my full path where the X's are because I am not allowed to.

Comment: You must make the script executable (`chmod +x testscript`) or alter the crontab entry to start the command with `/bin/bash `.  `root` mail is often handled differently, try to execute `mail` as root and see if the mails are there.

Comment: Also check if root's sh is bash, it may be dash.

Comment: The duplicate is for Ruby but the answer is the same; you are assuming incorrect things about which directory you are in when `cron` runs your job.

Comment: If you started the file path with `home/...`, that's going to be a problem -- it almost certainly should start with a slash, like `/home/...`. Paths that start with a slash are called "absolute", and start at the top of the system volume. Paths that don't are "relative" and start wherever the process's current working directory is (for cron jobs, this is usually the account's home directory, i.e. different for your jobs vs root's). The same holds for the cronjobOutput file.

Comment: Concerning the ".sh" extension: always use the actual filename. If the filename ends in ".sh", then include that extension when running it. If it doesn't have an actual ".sh" in the name, then don't add it when running it.